# Compressing Video using HEVC Codec with swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, avassetwriter, swift4

Apple is using a new video codec hevc and i am trying to compress videos with my application using the hevc codec. For some reason the app just crashes and returns the file size as 0 mb. It works when i compress it using H264, however when I use H265(HEVC), the app just crashes. This is my code.

I am assuming there is something wrong with the way i am outputting the file. For right now, I am using an mov file. Should i be using another type of file extension for the specific HEVC codec. I am not too sure what is going on here.

```
func compressFile(urlToCompress: URL, completion:@escaping (URL)->Void){
    //video file to make the asset

    var audioFinished = false
    var videoFinished = false



    let asset = AVAsset(url: urlToCompress)

    //create asset reader
    do{
        assetReader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
    } catch{
        assetReader = nil
    }

    guard let reader = assetReader else{
        fatalError("Could not initalize asset reader probably failed its try catch")
    }

    let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first!
    let audioTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first!

    let videoReaderSettings: [String:Any] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String!:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB]

    // ADJUST BIT RATE OF VIDEO HERE

    let videoSettings:[String:Any] = [
        AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: [AVVideoAverageBitRateKey:self.bitrate],
        AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.hevc,
        AVVideoHeightKey: videoTrack.naturalSize.height,
        AVVideoWidthKey: videoTrack.naturalSize.width
    ]


    let assetReaderVideoOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack, outputSettings: videoReaderSettings)
    let assetReaderAudioOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: audioTrack, outputSettings: nil)


    if reader.canAdd(assetReaderVideoOutput){
        reader.add(assetReaderVideoOutput)
    }else{
        fatalError("Couldn't add video output reader")
    }

    if reader.canAdd(assetReaderAudioOutput){
        reader.add(assetReaderAudioOutput)
    }else{
        fatalError("Couldn't add audio output reader")
    }

    let audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio, outputSettings: nil)
    let videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: videoSettings)
    videoInput.transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
    //we need to add samples to the video input

    let videoInputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue")
    let audioInputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "audioQueue")
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
    let date = Date()
    let documentsPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    let outputPath = "\(documentsPath)/\(formatter.string(from: date)).mov"
    let newOutputUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)

    do{
        assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: newOutputUrl, fileType: AVFileType.mov)
    }catch{
        assetWriter = nil
    }
    guard let writer = assetWriter else{
        fatalError("assetWriter was nil")
    }

    writer.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    writer.add(videoInput)
    writer.add(audioInput)


    writer.startWriting()
    reader.startReading()
    writer.startSession(atSourceTime: kCMTimeZero)


    let closeWriter:()->Void = {
        if (audioFinished && videoFinished){
            self.assetWriter?.finishWriting(completionHandler: {

                self.checkFileSize(sizeUrl: (self.assetWriter?.outputURL)!, message: "The file size of the compressed file is: ")
                completion((self.assetWriter?.outputURL)!)
                print("Completed 1")

            })

            self.assetReader?.cancelReading()

        }
    }


    audioInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: audioInputQueue) {
        while(audioInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData){
            let sample = assetReaderAudioOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
            if (sample != nil){
                audioInput.append(sample!)
            }else{
                audioInput.markAsFinished()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    audioFinished = true
                    closeWriter()
                    print("Completed 2")
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    videoInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: videoInputQueue) {
        //request data here

        while(videoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData){
            let sample = assetReaderVideoOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
            if (sample != nil){
                videoInput.append(sample!)
            }else{
                videoInput.markAsFinished()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    videoFinished = true
                    print("Completed 3")
                    closeWriter()
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }


}

func checkFileSize(sizeUrl: URL, message:String){
    let data = NSData(contentsOf: sizeUrl)!
    print(message, (Double(data.length) / 1048576.0), " mb")
}
```

Comment: HEVC encoding is only available on iPhone 7 / 7+ and better. On which device did you test?

Comment: The HEVC encoder is not working properly through AVFoundation as of iOS 11.0.3. If you get past the crash, check out the file size using HEVC vs H264.

Comment: Do you have any update on this?